# c++: array's size changed after passed to a function

Tags: c++, arrays

i am a newbie to c++, as i wrote program to test how to pass array as the parameters in function, i wrote this little program:

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pass_by_array(int a[]) {
int a_len = sizeof(a);
int e_len = sizeof(a[0]);

cout << "size of array in func: " << a_len << endl;
cout << "size of element in func: " << e_len << endl;
}

int main() {
int foo[] = {1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6};

int a_len = sizeof(foo);
int e_len = sizeof(foo[0]);

cout << "size of array in main: " << a_len << endl;
cout << "size of element in main: " << e_len << endl;

pass_by_array(foo);

return 0;
}
```

---

here's the result i got:

```
size of array in main: 24
size of element in main: 4
size of array in func: 8
size of element in func: 4
```

so what the hell is going on there? the size of the array changed?!

Comment: Everything you need on C and C++ style arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/1619294

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying and see the accepted answer

Comment: You never passed the size of the array to `pass_by_array`, so how is it supposed to know? (Consider if `pass_by_array` is in a separate compilation unit.)

Answer (score 4):

When you pass an array to a function, it decays into a pointer to its first element. Therefore `sizeof(a)` actually gives you the size of a *pointer* to `int`. On your machine, it appears that this is 8.

If you want to pass an array to a function such that the array still knows its size, use `std::vector` or `std::array`, not a plain C-style array.

Answer (score 0):

As per your program:

```
int a_len = sizeof(foo);
int e_len = sizeof(foo[0]);
```

is a `function` `variable` so `compiler` can interpret it as an `array` because it is on same `stack frame` of the function where it is `declared` and `initialized`.

For your program:
`main()`

And when you pass an array to another function

```
pass_by_array(foo);
```

it is converted as a pointer which is been defined in the stack frame of the receiving function and stores the address of the array.

So because of that as per your program:

```
int a_len = sizeof(a);
int e_len = sizeof(a[0]);
```

first statement will give you the size of `int* a` i.e. `sizeof (pointer)` or `int` as per the `compiler`.
As pointers can be used as an array `a[0]` it will give you the `sizeof(int)`

Hope this will help you to understand.