# C++: Create function that returns array size

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a function in C++ that returns size of any array using pointers:
`*(&array + 1) - array`.
like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void arrayLength(string array[]) {
    int arraySize = *(&array + 1) - array;
    
    cout << "Size of the array: " << arraySize << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    string myArray[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    arrayLength(myArray);
//  Output: It seems to return the size in bytes (different numbers like this: 381286345)

    return 0;
}
```

And this Code works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string array[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    cout << *(&array + 1) - array << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&array + 1` is nonsense. What do you think `&array` in *every* context it is used in this code *does*. ?

Comment: You cannot determine the size of a pointed to array from a pointer, so your function can never work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078435/635608

Comment: duplicate: [size of array passed to C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3062005/995714), [When passing an array to a function in C++, why won't sizeof() work the same as in the main function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36525798/995714), [c++: array's size changed after passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22187990/995714)

Comment: In C++17 and later, use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice demonstration why are ordinary raw arrays dangerous.

The issue is with pointer arithmetic and `+1`. For `T* ptr;`, `ptr+1` advanced the pointer by `sizeof(T)` bytes, or one `T`.

In main, `&array` is of type `string(*)[4]`, so the pointer is incremented by `sizeof(string)*4`. This leads to the correct size.

On contrary, `string array[]` in `arrayLength()` has type `string*` even if you use `[]`. The increment is only `sizeof(string*)` in bytes thus leading to incorrect size.

Just use `std::array` or `std::vector` with their `size()`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer that you should use `std::array` or `std::vector` if possible. If however, you are not allowed to use the STL or have other good reasons to use plain C arrays, then there is a possible template solution:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
size_t getArrayLength(T(&arr)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Just call this template with any array as parameter. Note that calling this with a pointer won't work, but at least you get a compiler error instead of weird runtime behaviour.

Comment: It can be also constexpr